# How to compare Time variables?

Tags: vb.net

I have 3 variables of type DateTime or string type, in the form `hh:mm:ss`.

For example:

```
dT1="00:00:00"
dT2="20:59:59"
dT3="18:04:21"
```

How can I perform the following comparison?

```
  dT1<= dT3 <= dT2 ??
```

Comment: I think if you convert them to TimeSpan objects you should be able to compare them quite easily

Comment: Why are you asking us how to compare variables? This site is not to teach you the basics or write your code for you. If you want to compare variables, compare them. If you can't work out how to compare three variables - which is very easy if you actually try - then search for it online as there will undoubtedly be examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Dim dT1 As DateTime = New DateTime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)        ' 00:00:00
Dim dT2 As DateTime = New DateTime(2020, 1, 1, 20, 59, 59)     ' 20:59:59
Dim dT3 As DateTime = New DateTime(2020, 1, 1, 18, 04, 21)     ' 18:04:21

If dT1 <= dT3 <= dT2 Then
    'your code
End If
```

Hope, it helps :)

Comment: Quindi se ho  `sT1="00:00:00"
                       sT2="20:59:59"
                       sT3="18:04:21" ` posso definire `dT1 as Datetime=sT1,dT2 as DateTime=sT2,dT3 as DateDateTime=sT3` e quindi poter fare `If dT1 <= dT3 <= dT2 Then
    'my code
End If` Grazie a tutti

Answer (score 3):

Your example show String not DateTime. I put your strings in and array called TimeStrings. Then I created a List of TimeSpan. Looping through the strings I split each string on the colon, then created a new TimeSpan and added it to the list. I used the .Max method of the list to get the highest value in the list.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    'Constructor TimeSpan(Int32, Int32, Int32)
    Dim dT1 = "00:00:00"
    Dim dT2 = "20:59:59"
    Dim dT3 = "18:04:21"
    Dim TimeStrings = {dT1, dT2, dT3}
    Dim Spans As New List(Of TimeSpan)
    For Each s In TimeStrings
        Dim Splits = s.Split(":"c)
        Dim span As New TimeSpan(CInt(Splits(0)), CInt(Splits(1)), CInt(Splits(2)))
        Spans.Add(span)
    Next
    Dim HighestValue = Spans.Max
    MessageBox.Show(HighestValue.ToString)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [TimeSpan.Parse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse), [ParseExact()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parseexact), [TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tryparse) or [TryParseExact()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tryparseexact) to convert the string to a TimeSpan value. The comparison is straightforward after that:

Add your string values to a collection (an Array or List of strings).

```
Dim dTs As String() = {"00:00:00", "23:59:59", "20:59:59", "23:10:21", "18:04:21"}

Dim max As TimeSpan = dTs.Select(
    Function(s) TimeSpan.ParseExact(s, "hh\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).Max()
```

**`max`** will be `23:59:59`

Of course you can order the TimeSpan value, in ascending order here:

```
Dim orderedTimeSpans =
    dTs.Select(Function(s) TimeSpan.ParseExact(s, "hh\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).
        OrderBy(Function(ts) ts).ToList()

orderedTimeSpans.ForEach(Sub(ts) Console.WriteLine(ts))
```

Which prints:

```
00:00:00
18:04:21
20:59:59
23:10:21
23:59:59
```

With `TryParseExact()`, if you're not sure whether the format is may not be correct (possibly, because the source of the values is not reliable - User input, for example):

```
Dim parsed As TimeSpan
Dim max As TimeSpan =
    dTs.Select(Function(s) TimeSpan.TryParseExact(s, "hh\:mm\:ss",
               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, parsed)).Max(Function(t) parsed)
```

This also returns `23:59:59`.
If one of the values cannot be parsed, it won't be evaluated by the `Max()` method.

E.g., if this is the input string `"23.59:59"`, `InvariantCulture` and the format specified won't allow to return a valid TimeSpan, so the max value will be `23:10:21` instead.

The same, using `TryParseExact()`, but in *extended* form (using a loop):

```
Dim maxValue As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan()
Dim parsed As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan()
For Each value As String In dTs
    If TimeSpan.TryParseExact(value, "hh\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, parsed) Then
        maxValue = If(TimeSpan.Compare(maxValue, parsed) > 0, maxValue, parsed)
    End If
Next
```